# Gedankenexperiment to derive the Robertson uncertainty relation without confusing it with the obersver effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, education, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In the last years there seemed to be much activity on the meaning Heisenberg's uncertainty relation. The main point of the discussion was Heisenbergs noise-disturbance-relation (see: http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0207121 and citing papers). Even if today people seem to distinguish conceptually between noise-disturbance-relations and the Robertson uncertainty relation, the classical Gedankenexperiments, like Heisenberg's microscope seem to confuse both relations a bit and seem to rely more on the observer effect than emphasizing the statistical nature of the Robertson relation.

Is there any clear Gedankenexperiment accessible to (advanced) high-school students which "derives" (in the weak sense of making it plausible) the Robertson uncertainty relation without confusing it with the observer effect and the noise-disturbance relation?

In particular I am interested in the position-momentum Robertson uncertainty relation.

Comment: The position-momentum Robertson uncertainty relation is a consequence of the properties of the Fourier transformation. Why not work with classical wave-packets and see how a narrow wave-packet induces a wide frequency band, etc.?

Comment: @Martin I guess this will be mathematically to advanced for high school level.

Comment: @Julia I tend to agree, talking about such mathematical technicalities such as the Robertson inequality or foggy ideas such as Heisenberg microscope, even if done thoughtfully, would be useful for vanishing fraction of high school students.   This belongs to later education of a physicist, when he/she learns fundamentals of theory of probability, statistics in experiments, Cauchy inequality, Schroedinger equation and its probabilistic use. You cannot teach them these things in  few hours, it takes months. I'd tell them rather what we know about thunders, how battery or fridge works etc.

Comment: @JánLalinský It's part of the curriculum and I don't want to make the ideas too wrong (for example by confusing the Robertson relation with the noise-disturbance relation...)!

Comment: How old are your students? I doubt high school students will be able to comprehend these things without knowledge of the necessary mathematics.

Comment: 17 - 19 years old (a German Gymnasium, grade 13)